# How to write tfs work item query for fetching workitems which are under more than one iteration path

Tags: tfs, tfs-query

I want to write a tfs work item query like below

- (Team  project **=** @Project)
- AND (Assigned to **=** user1 OR Assigned to **=** user2 OR Assigned to **=** user3)
- AND (Iteration path **under** path1 OR Iteration path **under** parth2)

Please help me in achieving the same.

Below is what i am trying to do, but its not giving me desired results.

[image]

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Have added the screen shot of what i am trying to make my desired query, but it is not giving valid result.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the problem.

The problem was with the first class where i was using Team project = @Project

and @Project was set to one iteration path and hence it was always showing the result from one iteration path.

Removing the first class solved the problem.